# passing values between two jsp files

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
  <%   if(empRecNum != null && !(empRecNum.equals("")))
        {
           empSelected=true;
        }
        boolean canModify = UTIL.hasSecurity("PFTMODFY") && empSelected;
%>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function add(){
        alert('hello');
        df('ADD');
    }

</script>
```

On the click of add button, i need to pass the boolean value to another jsp and then go on with the df servlet function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, which may help:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/caller.jsp.html

Answer (score 3):

pass in URL like

```
second.jsp?param=value
```

access param from second jsp

```
request.getParameter("param");
```

**OR**: 
Store it in cookie

**OR**:
Persist it in DB